# How to increment environment variable in 5

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, cypress, increment

Each time I run the test suit, I want to use a different set of parameters.

```js
{
  "Company": {
    "Name": "CompnayName1040",
    "FullName": "FullName1040",
    "phone": "0505551040"
  }
}
```

After each test run I'm running a last test that will increment by 5 the above variables

When running this code the result phone number is: 05055510405

```
cy.readFile('cypress.env.json', ).then( (envVars) => {
cy.log('Old cypress.env.json.Employee.phone: '+envVars.Employee.phone);
envVars.Employee.phone = String(envVars.Employee.phone).replace(/(\d{4})$/, function(n){ return n+=5 });
cy.log('New cypress.env.json.Employee.phone: '+envVars.Employee.phone);
}
```

I was expecting the phone number to be 0505551045

Comment: The 5 gets appended to the original phone number, since it is a string

Comment: You do not need String() around a string variable in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

To bump the phone number, work with the last 7 digits.

This will preserve your leading "0".

```js
const head = envVars.Employee.phone.substr(0,3)
const tail = envVars.Employee.phone.substr(3)
const bumped = +tail+5
envVars.Employee.phone = `${head}${bumped}`
```

---

Using @jjhelguero's idea for random numbers, you might like to try use [fakerjs phoneNumber](https://fakerjs.dev/api/phone.html)

```js
envVars.Employee.phone = faker.phone.phoneNumber('05055510##')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to use unique strings, you can also use the lodash, which is bundled with Cypress, function `.random()`. Example

```js
Name = `CompanyName${Cypress._.random(9999)}` // random number between 0 and 9999
```

Comment: Random is not good for me as i want to monitor  the creation of new employee each test suit run

Comment: If you are running the tests multiple times, it might be easier to generate a unique string each time and then log those so it will be easier to grab and track each new employee.

Answer (score 0):

I used this loop to increase by 5 the mobile number of the created employee:

```
for (var i=0; i<5; ++i) {
     envVars.Company.phone = string(envVars.Company.phone).replace(/(\d{4})$/, function(n){ return ++n })}
```